# How to solve CORS policy issue in a fullstack app

Tags: express, vue.js, cors, axios

I am building a MEVN-stack app, but I fail to make a request from my fron-end to the server due to Cross origin policies. I have enabled the cors middleware for all routes, but it does not take effect. I also tried applying it on each route individually and to specify the origin, but still no effect.

index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const BanksController = require('./controllers/BanksController')
const OfficesController = require('./controllers/OfficesController')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const app = express()

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3001' }))

app.get('/api/banks', BanksController.index)
app.get('/api/offices', OfficesController.index)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Listening on port ' + PORT))
```

the ajax request:

```
axios.get('localhost:3000/api/banks')
          .then(res => console.log(res))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Could you please include the full error message?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/api/banks' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```js
axios.get('localhost:3000/api/banks')
```

to this:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/banks')
```

Notice how the error message complains about the protocol scheme.

The problem is not your server. The problem is that using `localhost:3000` treats `localhost:` as a scheme. The 'scheme' is the bit of the URL before the first colon.

You won't even see the request in the Network section of the developer tools because the browser doesn't know how to make a `localhost:` 'request'.

Comment: You are totally right! I didn't even think of my actual request as a source of the issue... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3001/*' }))
```

It will be enabled for all routes. Or just use:

```
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is unfortunately exactly what I've already tried doing.